# How to calculate total number of seconds from the time format HHMMSS? Do we have a direct function for this?

Tags: python, datetime

I have tried the following method but would like to know about a more simpler way.

```
def getSecFromHHMMSS(ts):
    hhInMins = int(str(ts)[0:2]) * 60 * 60
    mm = int(str(ts)[2:4]) * 60
    ss = int(str(ts)[4:6])
    return hhInMins + mm + ss;
```

Comment: could you care to format your question (it's not open for editing for some reason)

Comment: i think this is python question, not pyspark

Comment: why not just do  `return int(str(ts)[0:2])*3600 + int(str(ts)[2:4]) * 60 +int(str(ts)[4:6]) ` and get rid of variables that you never going to need.

Comment: `return sum(map(lambda d, w: int(d)*w, ts, [36000,3600,600,60,10,1]))` :)

Comment: Thanks rici,pushkr and muon for your prompt reply

Answer (score 0):

idea of *simpler* is relatively subjective. I think this is cleaner.

```
import datetime
import time

def get_seconds(ts):
    x = time.strptime(ts, '%H%M%S')
    _ts = (datetime.timedelta(hours=x.tm_hour,minutes=x.tm_min,seconds=x.tm_sec)
                   .total_seconds())
    return _ts


ts = '010101'
s = get_seconds(ts)
print(s)
```

gives

```
3661.0
```

or this one liner:

```
(datetime.timedelta(hours=int(ts[:2]),minutes=int(ts[2:4]),seconds=int(ts[4:]))
         .total_seconds())
```

Comment: Thanks muon for your inputs. By simpler i meant there must be a predefined function which could do the same thing.

Comment: that depends on your input, if you supply  input of format obtained from ``time.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')``  then it seems to be a oneliner, but not for non-standard string input

Comment: @Lalit I added a one liner, can't get simpler than this